# Discord JS | When attaching local image (MessageAttachment) to MessageEmbed, image appears outside of embed

Tags: discord.js

!! Still looking for a solution. I haven't found one myself and have reverted back to using internet links.

I am using Node v16.15.0 and Discord JS v13.7.0.

My problem here is that for some reason, the image attachment is showing up outside and before the embed when I want it to appear inside the embed. I've tried just about every iteration of attaching an image to an embed that I can find online both here and on any other website, but without any luck. Either the embed or the image doesn't appear at all, or it's like this (see image below) with the image appearing before the embed.

Here's the relevant code. id is a number, all image files are in a folder called images in the same directory as the bot code. All other information shows up exactly as it should.

```
let image = 'flag (' + id + ').png'
const attachment = new MessageAttachment('images/' + image);

let emb = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(country.name)
    .setColor('#000000')
    .addField('Sovereign', country.sovereign.toString(), true)
    .addField('Continent', country.continent, true)
    .addField('Subregion', country.subregion, true)
    .addField('Aliases', aliases, true)
    .setImage("attachment://" + image)
    .setTimestamp();
ch.send({ files: [attachment], embeds: [emb] });
```

I've also tried listing the embed before the files, tried using "embed: emb" (no embed shows up), and like a million other things. I'm not sure what to do.

[image: A screenshot of the image appearing before the embed.]

Answer (score 1):

first you're going to need to set an attachment name `image.png`. also your directory call was incorrect, when reaching through folder it should always be formatted like `./folder/`
then change the `.setImage()` to this:

```js
.setImage(`attachment://${image}.png`)
```

and you should be all good to send the embed with the file attached to it.

```js
ch.send({ embeds: [emb], 
files: [
  { 
    attachment: `./images/${image}.png`,
    name: `${image}.png` 
  }
]
});
```

Comment: Hello and thank you! I did have all this before to no effect, but I applied them again anyway to try... My image unfortunately still seems to be appearing outside of the embed, exactly as in the screenshot. Much less importantly, you're missing the '.png' in the `./images/${image}` for the first argument for the MessageAttachment constructor call. (or all the other ${image}s have an extra '.png')

Comment: yes you can add that

Comment: Please forgive my unfamiliarity with the site but add it to my code? (Already done! It wouldn't run otherwise.) Or to your answer? (I can't, says edit queue is full, but I think it's because I don't post enough in general.) Thank you!

Comment: Ahh thank you! Though unfortunately like I mentioned above, the image does still show up outside and before the embed, so I'm still where I started. Genuinely don't know why it's doing this.

Comment: i edited it to where you set message attachment in the files array and not initialize it as a variable

Comment: Tried this, but there's no change. I even tried copying and pasting exactly what you said in case I had a character wrong or something, but without luck. Thank you for your hard work though

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am using `discord.js v14.7.1` and `node v18.16.1`. The following line is outdated:

```js
const attachment = new MessageAttachment('images/' + image);
```

You can use a `AttachmentBuilder` instead:

```js
const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder('images/' + image)
  .setName('image.png');
```

Additionally, you can use the attachment as the embed's image without externally hosting it by refering to it in the embed using the `attachment://filename.extension` format in `EmbedBuilder#setImage()`:

```js
// Create an embed
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('This is your title')
  .setImage('attachment://image.png'); // Note the filename should match the one in the attachment
```

Which you'd then pass over as you normally would:

```js
ch.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [attachment] });
```